# Export GAL to Outlook contacts automatically

Tags: exchange-2010, iphone, contacts

Masters,

we need to sync all our contacts (Exchange 2010) with our Iphone mobiles (and maybee with android devices too..but later..).

So we need to add contacts from exchange gal to users contacts folder....

Is it possible to do this automatically? To keep the user contacts list up-to-date? I think if i can export GAL to Users contact as logon script or someting like this may do the trick for me?!

How its possible?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

Essentially you need to copy the GAL contacts from the address book to the user "Contacts" folder.  You should be able to use Powershell to access the Outlook API and the copy contact functions to copy from the GAL to the current user's folder in the default MAPI profile upon login / using a loginscript, or perhaps launch the script after successfully logging into exchange.

Comment: Its already done. First we export contacts to cvs with EWS. Than we made some formatting with DOS commands. Than we use DOS / Poweshell to import a mailbox. This mailbox connected every user's phones. (We have to change the throttling policy to connect more users to mailbox in same time..).
Plus we have to make a script / task which make an full empty than reload to this mailbox in every day. (because this is a common mailbox, if somebody modify or delete a contact, every phone sync it..)

Comment: but this now works?  lots of effort... congrats!

Answer (score 1):

Here is some 3rd party software that will do what you need.

http://www.connectedsw.com/Overview/57261

Answer (score 0):

This really seems unnecessary, an iphone or android device connected via activesync to an exchange account can search the GAL from the device.  Syncing all entries to everyone's contacts defeats the purpose of the GAL in the first place.  If users frequently contact particular users, they can add the entry to their contacts from the GAL and updates will be synced.

Comment: "Unnecessary" - as you think...We need this, thats why i open this topic. To search in the GAL from Iphone is minimum 4 plus click (with other issues..). Its not productive. And phone must be online. Activesnyc only sync the contacts and not the GAL. But if we sync GAL to Contacts, than its done... Thnx

Comment: The problem is that doing this will not scale.  As the number of entries in your GAL grow, the more contacts every user has to have.  Not only will this rapidly take up space on their phones, and their mailboxes, but at some threshold it is more cumbersome for the user.

Comment: Searching the GAL is also a user experience that many users hate. You can't browse the GAL, so if you don't remember how to spell something, you'll never find it using a GAL search.

Comment: your answer would be fine if you didn't have the first 4 words "This really seem unnecessary" - don't judge people's questions - just answer them (if you can/are inclined).